# Where do I find my personal files?

Tags: software-recommendation, backup, search, ubuntu-studio

Obviously, I'm a newbie after 35 years on Apple. Without the rant, I've decided to convert to Ubuntu Studio and convert time previously with MacOS engineering problems and invest in learning the new world in 19.10.

A basic problem not answered in my web searches:

Where do I find my files? My user-created documents from the various programs, in the Documents and Download folders. I cannot find them by search or poking around.

I want to re-install the OS but don't want to give up my documents from the past few weeks.

And I should probably start searching for some reliable time-triggered backup program for the new system.

A little help?

Comment: Re-installing.  I always opt for 'something-else' (or "Manual Partitioning", "Manual" depending on installer/flavor) where I can select the partitions I want (usually whatever I had previously) and select **not** to format so my files won't be touched. It erases system directories (only unless you format), installs, adds back packages (programs you installed last time!) etc... As for files, I always store files in directories I select, which isn't local but network storage (so they're available if I'm using a different box); but different programs can use different standards...

Comment: Discussions about the site need to go to Meta https://meta.askubuntu.com/ not inside a question :)

Answer (score 0):

> Where do I find my files?

Where -you- put them ;)

> My user-created documents from the various programs, in the Documents and Download folders. I cannot find them by search or poking around.

You only need to know the name of 1 of your files and the others will be near them though I would expect your files to be at

```
/home/$USER/
```

and in there inside a directory (Downloads/ or Documents/) but there is a command to have the system tell you:

```
locate {part of a file}
```

and it will list all found files since the last time a database where locate gets its information from was updated. If the files are not yet in there you can force an update first and then locate a file ...

```
sudo locatedb
{admin password}
locate {part of a file}
```

The same can be done from the file manager: there will be a magnifier. This search will search real time but from the place you start it so you can miss out on a file if it is outside your search scope.